# Normed Space Isometric to Proper Subspace of Itself

Tags: real-analysis, normed-spaces, isometry

I am trying to show that there exists a normed vector space which is isometric to a proper subspace of itself. I have been playing around with the $l^\infty$ norm on $\mathbb{N}$, but am struggling to find a specific mapping $f$ which maps to a subspace and is an isometry.

It's probably glaringly obvious, but I would appreciate a hint or a point in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the $\ell^2$ space of maps $\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{R}$. Then the $\ell^2$ space of maps $\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{R}$ which vanish on odd numbers is a proper subspace. The isomorphism comes from the bijection $2\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: Sorry? I'm in a brain fog today, so I'm likely misinterpreting, but I don't see the isomorphism. Suppose $f(2) = 1$. Then $\vert \vert f(2) \vert \vert \neq \vert \vert 2 \vert \vert$.

Comment: @Olivia Sorry if that was unclear. If $f(2)=1$, then the isomorphism defines a $g$ where $g(1)=1$. In general, given an $f:\mathbb{N}\to \mathbb{R}$ which only takes non-zero values on the evens, define $g$ by $g(n)=f(2n)$.

Comment: Aah thank you. :) I assumed that the mapping not only had to be isomorphic, but also had to take the whole space down to a subspace. I didn't realise we could pick any normed vector space along with any subspace, and try to find an isomorphic mapping. That simplifies things!